# 42 Crunch issue "String schema in a request has no pattern defined"

Tags: kotlin, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I am working on the 42 ceunch but i am getting one issue "String schema in a request has no pattern defined"

i am using plain string in request body instead of object. I am trying to apply the @Pattern & @size validation on my request in rest api but it was not working on swagger json.

can anyone please help ?

here is my code:

```
  @PostMapping("/proxy-request")
    fun processProxyRequest(
        @Pattern(regexp = GENERIC_STRING) @Size(max = 25) @RequestBody request: String,
        httpRequest: HttpServletRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        val response = proxyService.processRequest(request, allHeaders)
        logger.info("Exit from ProxyController.processProxyRequest : response -> $response")
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response)
    }
```

The @Pattern(regexp = GENERIC_STRING) @Size(max = 25) are not working on plain string how can i do that.
Thanks in Advance